# Unable to increase volume for music stream in Honeycomb and up

Tags: java, android

I have code that allows a user to issue an audible alert on their device. In Android 2.3 and below, I am able to issue the alert even if the sound is turned all the way down by programatically increasing the volume via `AudioManager.setStreamVolume`. However now in Android 3.x and up when I attempt to do this the native volume adjustment widget appears on the screen for a moment but the current volume still stays at zero. The code is below:

```
int currentVolume = audioMgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioMgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

// If the current volume is not set to the maximum level
if (currentVolume < maxVolume) {
    // Set the current volume to the maximum level
    audioMgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE);
}
```

My question is...what has changed in *Honeycomb* that makes this no longer work? I set a breakpoint after `setStreamVolume` and ran `getStreamVolume` by hand. It was still set to zero. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that `setStreamVolume` is ignored, but `adjustStreamVolume` is not. I still have to do more testing on non-*Honeycomb* devices but thus far this code appears to work:

```
while(audioMgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) < maxVolume) {
    audioMgr.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
}
```

Comment: This did work on Android 2.3 as well. Interestingly, when I did this the Grooveshark app force quit on me and I wasn't using it at the time.

Answer (score 3):

With ICS (Android 4.0.3) the problem remains but there is a working solution as well. Try using this code:

```
// The commented code below works with 2.3, but not with 4.0 (ICS)
//audioMgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, lvl, 0);

// Use this instead
while(audioMgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) > lvl) {
    audioMgr.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
}
while(audioMgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) < lvl) { 
    audioMgr.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
}
```